# How Validate input box array with file array in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

How to validate input box array with file array. I want to need first anyone text box will be required and if the first text box having value then first file input box it required but file input box required when input box having a value.

Validation Require:
 **1. anyone text field required.
 2. suppose equipment_needed[0] having value then img_equipment_needed[0] is** required.

Input Boxes:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipment_needed[]" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipment_needed[]" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipment_needed[]" value="">
```

Files:

```
<input class="form-control" name="img_equipment_needed[]" type="file">
<input class="form-control" name="img_equipment_needed[]" type="file">
<input class="form-control" name="img_equipment_needed[]" type="file">
```

I try:

```
$items = $request->validate([
             'equipment_needed' => required,             
             'img_equipment_needed'=>'required_if:equipment_needed',
             'required_with:equipment_needed','file',
         ]);
```

but no success.

Comment: I have more clarification.